# Laravel 5 keep redirecting me to `/auth/login` when go to an route post?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel 5.
I have a route post `/subscribe`.

```
//Subcribe
Route::post('/subscribe','SubscribeController@postSubscribe');
```

When I goto it, my Laravel application auto redirecting me to : `/auth/login`

I notice, in my

I have : `/app/Http/routes.php`

```
Route::controllers([
 'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
 'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
 ]);
```

---

## Auth Controller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar  $registrar
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->registrar = $registrar;

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

}
```

---

## PasswordController

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker  $passwords
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, PasswordBroker $passwords)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->passwords = $passwords;

        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

}
```

---

Request by @SW

## SubscribeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Subscribe;
use Input, Validator, Auth, Redirect, Request, Session, Mail, View;

class SubscribeController extends Controller {


    public function index()
    {

        $subscribes = Subscribe::all();

        return View::make('subscribes.index')
        ->with('subscribes',$subscribes);

    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [ Create]


    public function create()
    {

        return View::make('subscribes.create');
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [ Store ]


    public function store()
    {
        $validator = Subscribe::validator(Input::all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {


            return Redirect::to('subscribe/create')
            ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

        } else {


            $subscribe               = new Subscribe;
            $subscribe->email  = Input::get('email');
            $subscribe->save();

            return Redirect::to('/subscribe')
            ->with('success','The web directory was created succesfully!');

        }
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [ Show ]


    public function show($id)
    {

        $subscribe = Subscribe::findOrFail($id);
        return View::make('subscribes.show')
        ->with('subscribe', $subscribe);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [ Edit ]


    public function edit($id)
    {

        $subscribe = Subscribe::findOrFail($id);

        return View::make('subscribes.edit')
        ->with('subscribe', $subscribe );
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [ Update ]


    public function update($id)
    {
        $validation = Subscribe::validator(Input::all());

        if ($validation->fails()) {

            return Redirect::to('subscribe/'. $id . '/edit')->withErrors($validation);

        } else {


            $subscribe               = Subscribe::findOrFail($id);
            $subscribe->email  = Input::get('email');
            $subscribe->save();

            return Redirect::to('subscribe')
            ->with('success','The web directory was updated succesfully!');
        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [ Destroy ]

    public function destroy($id){

        $subscribe = Subscribe::find($id);

        $subscribe->delete();

        return Redirect::to('subscribe')
        ->with('success','The web directory was deleted succesfully!');

    }

    public function postSubscribe() {

        $subscribe_email = Input::only('subscribe_email');

        // Validation
        $validator = Validator::make( $subscribe_email ,

            array(

                'subscribe_email'  => 'email|unique:subscribes,email',
                )
            );

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return Redirect::to('/#footer')
            ->with('subscribe_error', $subscribe_email['subscribe_email']. ' is already an Aveniros subscriber.')
            ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

        }else{

            $subscribe        = new Subscribe;
            $subscribe->email = Input::get('subscribe_email');
            $subscribe->save();

            return Redirect::to('/thank-you');

        }

    }

    public function postSubscribeAjax() {

        $data = Request::all();

        //dd($data); Stuck HERE

        // Validation
        $validator = Validator::make( $data,

            array(
                'subscribe_email' => 'email|unique:subscribes,email',
                )
            );


        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return Redirect::to('/#footer')
            ->with('subscribe_error','This email is already subscribed to us.')
            ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

        }else{

            $subscribe = new Subscribe;
            $subscribe->email = Input::get('subscribe_email');
            $subscribe->save();
            return Redirect::to('/thank-you');

        }

    }



    public function thankyou() {
        return view('subscribes.thankyou');
    }



}
```

Why is that ? and how do I fix it ? Is this even a normal behavior ?

Comment: Could we see your `SubscribeController`?

Comment: Is it necessary ? - just curious.

Comment: The other two controllers you pasted wouldn't affect your route unless there was something in your `SubscribeController` telling them to.

Comment: Did you mean you were trying to access that route directly in your browser? It's a POST route, so you'll need to invoke a POST request. Normal browser requests are of the GET type.

Comment: If you try to call a url expecting a POST request, you also going to be dealing with the CsrfToken issue, which is enabled on all post routes by default in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a method for your each of your routes, telling Laravel how to treat each route. For example in your route file, there should be `Route::get('index@SubscribeController);` line. As Staurt Wagner has mentioned, if you just navigate to a path, you are sending get request to the server.

If you are using Laravel 5, your controllers should be in the `\app\Http\Controllers` path.
Your `index` method in the`SubscribeController` can simply be:

```
public function index(){
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

For a much thorough tutorial, refer to [this wonderful series](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/3) on Laracast.